# Why is my code not recoginising blank line C++

Tags: c++, get, getline, istream

I had a look at this example, on the `istream get` method to extract characters from a file stream.

Basically, I don't want my program to read a blank line, however it skips to the next line and gives an error that it can't read the next line - when really it shouldn't read the blank line.

Anyways, this is the tutorial I followed http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/ and this is my code

```
is.get(c)
if(c == '\0')
{
  cout << "Blank line" << endl;
}
else
{
 is.getline(...);
}

ignore whitespace...
is.getline(...);
```

Comment: This cannot be your code: it doesn't compile.

Comment: Use getline to read line to a string. If you do it in a while loop, you can basically check the size of the string to see if it is a blank line. To read characters, you can use the string as an array (if your string is 'line', then line[2] is the second character).

Comment: @learningToCode: actually, `line[2]` is the third character as arrays start with index zero.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Thank you. Characters from strings can be accessed with the array access operator. So, string line, line[0] is the first character.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be under the impression that a blank line is somehow represented by a null character. It is not. A blank line just consists of an end of line character (`'\n'`, possible originally of a line end sequence but on systems where it matters the line end sequence is transfirmed into a line end character in non-`std::ios_base::binary` mode). To detect an empty line you'd read a line using `std::getline()` or, possibly, using `std::istream::getline()` and check if the result is empty.